# Length of a string in Javascript is always 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

So I have some really irritating problems. I run a function basically like this:

```
function printText(message){
    console.log(message.length);
    console.log(message);
    console.log(message.length);
}
```

The output in the console log is:

```
1
Hello World!
1
```

I know that the value is 1 also because I test it in a if statement later. The next time I run the function it gives me the correct length of the string. But not the first time.

I get the message variable with an AJAX call to a local server. I mean, the message looks like it should so how can it forget this property? I don't understand anything.

The JSON call is pretty forward:

```
$.getJSON(sendURL, function(data) {
    printText(data.message);
});
```

I also have some other problems with this function. The strings are correct because I print them but they don't behave like they should. But I can't even explain what is wrong because everything seems fine but the result is not correct.

Comment: show the value of data.message

Comment: I suspect you'll find, if you debug, that `message` is an array containing a single string. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: Can I maybe extract any other useful data from this mysterious variable that could be useful?

Comment: `typeof data.message` ... `Array.isArray(data.message)`

Comment: What console are you using? If it is an array, that would be a surprising output.

Comment: It says that the type is an object

Comment: It is reproducible alright... `printText(['Hello World!'])` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the value to String and try to get the length like:

```
 console.log(String(message).length);
```

Comment: It worked! I don't know how but somehow the strings are not matured or something the first time I call the function on page start up. Thanks! Saved me a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

The input parameter `message` is being passed in as an array. When it's passed into the `printText()` method as an array, then the length of the array will be 1. If the input parameter is passed in as either a string or a variable containing a string, then the length will be 12.

Check out this code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/q9xz565u/). Open the console & run it. Then the problem will become clear!

```
function printText(message){
    console.log(message.length);
    console.log(message);
    console.log(message.length);
}

console.log ('String Test');
printText('Hello World!'); // This will print string length = 12

console.log ('Variable Test');
let message = 'Hello World!';
printText(message); // This will print string length = 12

console.log ('Array Test');
message = ['Hello World!'];
printText(message); // This will print array length = 1
```

Comment: Yep, It is true, it seems to be an array, but this is strange since it I am sending a dictionary from my server in JSON-format which only contains strings. And as I said, the second time it is not an array but a string for some reason...

Comment: Try using the typeof keyword on the JSON object to see what it shows. Like: `console.log(typeof jsonDictionary);`. If there is a set of bracket `[]` which are wrapped around the JSON object, like this: `[{"key":"value"}]`, then it's outputting the JSON object inside of an array.